# How to solve this odd system of equations?

Tags: exponential-function, systems-of-equations

How can I solve for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$, $b$, and $c$ given these two equations? $a$, $b$, and $c$ are known to be positive real numbers.

$$ b = \exp \Big[-a \cdot (1 + (1+x)^{-y}) \Big] $$
$$ c = \exp \Big[-a \cdot (1 + (1+x)^{-y} + (1 + 2x)^{-y}) \Big] $$

There are two equations and two unknowns so it should in theory be possible, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the given equations, we can isolate the two quantities
$$
\begin{aligned}
(1+x)^{-y} &=A\ ,\\
(1+2x)^{-y} &=B\ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $A,B$ are "easily" written in terms of $a,b,c$. Now we take logarithms and build the quotient, so **EDITED**
$$
\frac {\ln(1+x)}{\ln(1+2x)}=\frac{\ln A}{\ln B}\ .
$$
This leads to a transcendental equation in $x$. This determines $x$. From the first equation above, say, we obtain $y$.

Note: Many thanks go to [g-kov](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/122782/g-kov) for pointing out an awful error...

Comment: It's also good to notice that $$c=\text{b} \text{exp}\left[(1+2x)^{-y}\right]$$

Comment: Thanks! Any tips on the method you'd use to solve the transcendental equation?